# asp.net vb Directcast Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to get the values from a dynamically created textbox(es) using an update panel. The line that keeps failing is:

> strName = DirectCast(pnlVars.Controls(strNameString),
>   TextBox).ToString

Error **System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.**

The strNameString variable is created dynamically but is a string link fwID.

Here's the whole loop.

```
For i = 0 To strArr.Count - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            qtype = " WHERE "
        Else
            qtype = " AND "
        End If
        strNameString = strArr(i).ToString().Replace("[", "fw").Replace("]", "")

        strName = DirectCast(pnlVars.Controls(strNameString), TextBox).ToString

        If strName <> "" Or strName <> Nothing Then
            sb.Append(qtype & strArr(i).ToString() & " = '" & strName & "' ")
        End If
    Next
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try it on multiple line to see where the error is

```
   Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(pnlVars.Controls(strNameString), TextBox)
   strName = tb.Text
```

If the error is on the first line, look at the value inside strNameString and make sure it's properly formatted.

As you can also see, I didn't use ToString() this wouldn't return what you want. You want the text inside the textbox.

Make sure strName is an actual string and not something else. In vb.net, it's not recommended to prefix variable with their type.

If that's for a query, don't concatenate the data in your query. Use parameters!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've tried it on multiple lines and it fails on the top line with error **System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "fwID" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'** Any ideas?

Comment: @BenWilliams looks like strNameString is an integer and not a string. Do you have: Dim strNameString As String  ?

Comment: Yeah- that is the odd thing. It's set as a string because the ID value is a string. I'm not sure where it's getting integer from

Comment: @BenWilliams how do you initialize strNameString ? Do right-click\Go To Definition

Comment: strNameString = strArr(i).ToString().Replace("[", "fw").Replace("]", "") - this is within my  array